# Is it possible to emulate an NFC tag on Android and read it with Iphone without it opening ApplePay?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, nfc, core-nfc

I have an android application on Flutter that would have to act as the NFC card with a URL. When another android or iPhone phone gets close/reads it, it should pop up as if it was reading a physical NFC card.

For example, I could have a universal link on iPhone that gets triggered when it reads the NFC message.

Is this possible? I have been looking at lots of documentation, but can't find a clear answer or solution or the topic. If possible, would I need to have an app on the second device to be reading or could I just use the background NFC service that IOS has on all newer devices?

I tried to follow the [Android Host Based Card guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce#supported-protocols) on the flutter app, but to no avail. And when I use any of the Card Emulators available on the Play Store and I tap with another phone, if phone #2 is:

- Apple: It opens apple pay
- Android: It prompts you to select a certain app from a short list (a couple banks and a crypto wallet). Although not sure what specifically makes those apps "special" cause other "Finance" apps don't show up.

The same message on an actual NFC Card 14443-3A NTAG216, opens the correct link.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: to avoid opening apple pay, you should use apple pay suppression entitlement

Comment: Hey @KuvonchbekYakubov thank you for your answer! So I would have to use an App on the iphone that suppressed Apple Pay before tapping, correct? Is it not possible to make the NDEF message in the HCE in a specific way that doesn't trigger Apple Pay? Or disable reading in the phone being used as HCE so as to not trigger the Apple Pay response?

Comment: `So I would have to use an App on the iphone that suppressed Apple Pay before tapping, correct?` Yes, correct.
I am still looking for solutions for this issue. NFC enabled any device can trigger Apple Pay on iPhone without any apps or HCE when you put them closer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that on the NTAG216 you put a url as an Ndef message.

With Host Card Emulation you can emulate lots of different types of Tags, each with it's own Application ID (AID), I don't know what AID's that the Apps you tried use, but to emulate a Tag that is storing Ndef data you need to use the Ndef AID `D2760000850101h`

I've not seen anything on flutter that emulates an NDef Tag, but really flutter is not suited for this as it has to be Native Java/Kotlin code for HCE, but you could try out https://github.com/underwindfall/NFCAndroid which emulates a Ndef Text Record, so you would have change it to emulate a Ndef URI record type instead (Note I've not tried this project)